# Unable to delete a worksheet using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am using this code:

```
ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);

var wk = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Content");

pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete(wk);
```

But in delete it gives me "IndexOutOfRangeException", but I am trying to delete from object, I have tried to delete by index "1", I just have two worksheets, and the same exception. The file and worksheet is not null, but when I execute delete in anyway I receive the "IndexOutOfRangeException".

What's happening?

Note: I have created this worksheet from ExcelPackage too and now i want delete it.

Comment: Are you sure wk isn't null?

Comment: I'm having the same exception with this one-liner: `while (wb.Worksheets.Count > 0) wb.Worksheets.Delete(0);`.

Comment: BTW, when changing my code to `while (wb.Worksheets.Count > 0) wb.Worksheets.Delete(1);`, no exception occurs. Seems that the index is one-based, not zero-based.

Comment: [This seems to be a similar issue](http://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/14929).

Comment: You haven't added any worksheets called "Content" so why wouldn't wk be null?

Comment: Did you post the actual code you're using? Because you should be getting a KeyNotFoundException, not a IndexOutOfRangeException.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you ran into some temporary bug/issue, that was already fixed. As of EpPlus 4.0.1.1, the following code works just fine:

```
var workbookFileInfo = new FileInfo(@"Workbook.xlsx");
using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(workbookFileInfo))
{
    excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet1");
    excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet2");
    excelPackage.Save();
}
using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(workbookFileInfo))
{
    var worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Worksheet1");
    excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete(worksheet);
    excelPackage.Save();
}
```

Try to update to the latest available stable version of EpPlus and if will not help you, please post additional details applicable for the latest version.