# Deleting worksheets not working

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm trying to delete all Worksheets without "Week" or "Month" contained in their names.I tried the code below:

```
var workbookFileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(workbookFileInfo))
{
    List<string> listNames = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Where(t => !t.Name.Contains("Week") && !t.Name.Contains("Month")).Select(t =>t.Name).ToList();
    foreach (string name in listNames)
    {
        excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete(name);
    }              
    excelPackage.Save();
}
```

But it causes the following error in the for loop:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in EPPlus.dll
>
> Additional information: Part does not exist.

How can I delete properly?

Answer (score 0):

In general, deleting from a collection is not allowed to be done with a for-each loop. Once you delete something from the collection, there is no "next".

Thus, you should loop a bit differently:

```
for (int i = Worksheets.Count; i > 0; i--)
{
     //delete by index here
}
```

See the logic in VBA, in C# it is absolutely the same - [Deleting worksheets with looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220661/deleting-worksheets-with-looping)

**However, this is not the case here, as far as the two collections (the one we are looping with and the one we are deleting are different).**

---

I have not installed the XML SDK, but this is something that worked from me:

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;    
class LooperMain
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
        excel.Visible = true;
        Excel.Workbook wkb = Open(excel, @"C:\testa.xlsx");

        for (int i = wkb.Worksheets.Count; i > 0; i--)
        {
            Excel.Worksheet sheet = wkb.Worksheets[i];

            Console.WriteLine(i);
            Console.WriteLine(sheet.Name);
            if (sheet.Name == "something")
            {
                sheet.Delete();
            }
        }
    }

    public static Excel.Workbook Open(Excel.Application excelInstance, 
            string fileName, 
            bool readOnly = false, 
            bool editable = true, 
            bool updateLinks = true)
    {
        Excel.Workbook book = excelInstance.Workbooks.Open(
            fileName, updateLinks, readOnly,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, editable, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        return book;
    }
}
```

Dependancies: In order to be able to declare like this:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

you need to add the MS Object Library (References> Add Reference> COM Search> Select> OK):

[image]

Comment: foreach and for is not making a difference, the collection being deleted is different from the collection in the foreach

Comment: @kadzu - quite true, actually. But are you sure that you have a workbook with the same name with each member of the list?

Comment: Yes, because the list is made from all names in the workbook

Comment: @kadzu - see the edit. In your case, simply declare the sheet and then delete it, the same way as I do it in the loop. Should work.

Comment: This code runs the excel program, I dont wish to use interop bacause of that.

Comment: @kadzu- still try to set a worksheet every time in the for loop and delete it. Probably it will work.

Comment: Also didnt work, same error. I think its a bug from EPPlus like @Caius said

Comment: I will create a new Excel instance, copy the worksheets I dont wish to delete into the new instance and delete the old file. There seems no other way.

Comment: @mjwills - in a way now it looks better. I have left a bit of it, as far as whenever I see looping through collection with for-each and deleting an alarm bell rings.

Answer (score 0):

This question: [Unable to delete a worksheet using EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415693/unable-to-delete-a-worksheet-using-epplus)

Has answers that seem to indicate you might be better passing a Worksheet object that is to be deleted into .Delete() rather than a string

```
var sheets = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Where(t => !(t.Name.Contains("Week") || t.Name.Contains("Month"))).ToList();
foreach (var sheet in sheets)
{
    excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete(sheet);
}              
excelPackage.Save();
```

Please note, I adjusted the logic of string contains, as I'm not convinced that `!t.Name.Contains("Week") || !t.Name.Contains("Month")` means "sheets that have neither week nor month in the name" - If a sheet is called `Week 1` then the name.contains(week) check will return true, negated to false, OR the name.contains(month) check will return false, negated to true, and the sheet will be listed for deletion

The logic, i believe, should be one of:

```
!name.contains(week) AND !name.contains(month)

!(name.contains(week) OR name.contains(month))
```

If it doesn't work out, try a delete by index:

```
for(int i = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Length; i>=1; i--){
  var name = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[i].Name.ToLower();
  if(name.Contains("week") || name.Contains("month")
    continue;
  else
    excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete(i);
}
```

Note; the link indicated that indexing of this collection is 1 based, not 0 based. If you find it is 0 based, adjust the loop accordingly

The reason why we delete in reverse order is a trick; deleteing the last item off a collection, doesn't disrupt the index of the next item we have to delete whereas deleting in a forwards order means the indexes of all the remaining items shift up by one, so if we just i++, we could skip one every time we delete one

Comment: Thanks, the logic was wrong too, but it's not the cause of the error. The error is in the moment it deletes de sheet.

Comment: Note: I've never used the EPPlus - the length of the sheets collection might be .Count, not .Length - you might have to adjust the "delete by index" example accordingly

Comment: It sounds more like a bug in EPPlus then; if you can literally say `Worksheets.Delete(1)` and it just bombs out. Which index value is causing the problem?